# AWS Amplify: The variables input contains a field name 'foo' that is not defined for input object type 'UpdateBarInput'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

*have seen similar question which they are updating relational models, but this is the main field* 
 
**the model design:**
[image]

**the query:**

```
  const { data } = await API.graphql({
    query: mutations.updateInvitation,
    variables: {
      input: { id: "invite id", status:"accepted" },
      authMode: "AWS_IAM",
    },
  });
```

the error:

```
{"data": null, "errors": [{"locations": null, "message": "The variables input contains a field name 'status' that is not defined for input object t
ype 'UpdateInvitationInput' ", "path": null}]}
```

so what is missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution in my case :
open the `schema.graphql` and look for `invitation` model,
add `status: String` field and then do `amplify push`(in terminal).

reply Yes to questions about regenerating mutations. 
you can read more in [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/overview#test-the-api)